# Loading entire content of a csv file into a single column in a Hive table

Tags: csv, hadoop, hive

Could use some help with a Hive related question.

I am trying to load an entire csv file into a single column Hive table. Each entry in the file should be a single row in the Hive table. I tried to change the ROW FORMAT - specifically tried to change to LINES TERMINATED BY ',' instead of '\n'. However, currently only the '\n' character is supported. It is currently a JIRA issue (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-11996).

The only idea I have currently is to replace the commas in the file with \n via a linux command however I wanted to see if anyone could propose some other solutions worth considering.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a temporary table in Hive then select each column apart. Let's a test file in HDFS "/tmp/test.csv" with this content:

> col1,col2,col3
>
> col4,col5,col6
>
> col7,col8,col9

If you create this temporary table:

```
CREATE TABLE tmp_csv(c1 STRING, c2 STRING, c3 STRING) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ",";

LOAD DATA INPATH '/tmp/test.csv' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE tmp_csv;
```

Then you can rebuild your table with the following:

```
CREATE TABLE final_csv AS SELECT * FROM 
(   SELECT t1.c1 as col FROM tmp_csv t1 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT t2.c2 as col FROM tmp_csv t2
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT t3.c3 as col FROM tmp_csv t3
)combined;
```

The content of table final_csv is this:

```
col1
col4
col7
col2
col5
col8
col3
col6
col9
```